# How to override default right-click menu in Gtk FileChooserWidget

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, right-click

The gtk FileChooserWidget shows a context menu on right-click with "add to bookmarks", "show hidden files", and "show size column" options.  I would like to override this menu with a custom menu.

Creating a menu on right-click from other gtk widgets (window, eventbox) is easy and there are a lot of tutorials out there showing how to do it.
I can't seem to get events from a gtk filechooser widget, however.  The "on_button_press_event" callback in the following code never gets called:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import gtk

class file_chooser_test():
    def __init__(self):
        window = gtk.Window()
        window.connect("delete_event", lambda w,e: gtk.main_quit())
        chooser = gtk.FileChooserWidget()
        chooser.set_size_request(600, 400)
        chooser.add_events(gtk.gdk.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK)
        chooser.connect("button-press-event", self.on_button_press_event)

        window.add(chooser)
        window.show_all()
        gtk.main()


    def on_button_press_event(self, widget, event=None):
        print "event is: ", event


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = file_chooser_test()
```

Can anyone shed any light on how to override the default right-click menu on the GTK FileChooserWidget?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if this is possible. Overriding `button-press-event` wouldn't do you much good because a GtkFileChooserWidget is made up of a bunch of other widgets, each with their own mechanism that GtkFileChooserWidget selectively decides to use for a right click menu. You could certainly ask on the GTK+ bug tracker for such a feature.

Comment: andlabs: I understand what you are getting at.  I'd prefer to be in control of selectively deciding which menu to display based on the current selection in the chooser, but I've still not found a way to do it.  I'll keep poking at it.  Thanks,